# How can I use nginx brotli_static with proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, proxy, brotli, ngx-brotli

nginx is compiled with Brotli enabled. In my nginx.conf

```
http {
    ...
    brotli_static on;
}
```

My .br files are located on a server with `proxy_pass`.

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://app;
}
```

And .br files have been generated on that `app` server:

```
$ ls -lh public/js/dist/index.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike wheel 1.2M Apr  4 09:07 public/js/dist/index.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike wheel 201K Apr  4 09:07 public/js/dist/index.js.br
```

Pulling down the uncompressed file works:

```
wget https://example.com/js/dist/index.js
```

Pulls down 1,157,704 size uncompressed file.

```
wget -S --header="accept-encoding: gzip" https://example.com/js/dist/index.js
```

Pulls down a 309,360 size gzipped file.

But:

```
wget -S --header="accept-encoding: br" https://example.com/js/dist/index.js
```

Still gets the full 1,157,704 size uncompressed file.

I had *hoped* `brotli_static` would proxy the .br file requests too - sending something a GET request to the backend for the .br equivalent resource - but this doesn't seem to work.

**Can brotli_static work through proxy_pass?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Maxim Dounin](https://twitter.com/mdounin) (an nginx core engineer)'s [comment on gzip_static](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/965#comment:3) - which I imagine brotli_static behaves similarly to - brotli_static only handles files, not HTTP resources:

> That is, gzip_static is only expected to work when nginx is about to return regular files.

So it looks like brotli_static and proxy_pass isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx config file needs a section to tell it to serve the static content folder.  You don't want your app server to do that.

I believe you'll need to place it before the `location /` so that it takes precedence.